# Glassfish/JAX-RS returning 404 despite apparent success

Tags: java, gradle, jersey, glassfish, jax-rs

I'm trying to create a simple webapp with Glassfish, Jersey, and Gradle. I have reached a point where Glassfish's Admin Page tells me that I have successfully deployed and the Glassfish logs say my project has deployed, but all requests 404 with "The requested resource is not available." I've spent quite a few hours trying/searching info online, but I have not been able to understand the error.

The URL I believe I should be visiting is localhost:8080/expenditures/test, but I have tried localhost:8080/expenditures, localhost:8080/test, etc. as sanity checks as well.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Directory structure:**

[image: Photo here, can't embed images yet]

**Web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app>
<display-name>Expenditures</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.expenditures</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Resource class:**

```
package com.expenditures;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/test")
public class ExpendituresServlet {

  @GET
  @Produces("text/plain")
  @Nonnull
  public String testHelloWorld() {
      return "Hello, world!";
  }
}
```

**build.gradle (which has a task launching the Glassfish server)**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin : 'idea'

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
    // main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/resources']
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet-core', version: '2.27'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-json-jackson', version: '2.27'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305
    compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '3.0.2'


}


//Trying to deploy to Glassfish...copied from
task run(dependsOn: 'war', type:Exec) {
    workingDir "dependencies/glassfish5/glassfish/bin"

    if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'asadmin.bat'
    } else {
        commandLine "./asadmin"
    }
    // args "stop-domain"
    args "deploy", "--force=true", "${war.archivePath}"
    // args "deploy", "${war.archivePath}"

}
```

I try to deploy by running:

```
./gradlew war && ./gradlew run
```

I have tried the following as well inside glassfish5/glassfish/bin with the same result:

```
./asadmin deploy --force=true /Users/Andrew/Documents/CodingProjects/expenditures/build/libs/expenditures.war
```

**Glassfish server.log ends with:**

```
[2018-07-21T18:15:47.648-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=42 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1532211347648] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [expenditures] at [/expenditures]]]

[2018-07-21T18:15:47.661-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=42 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1532211347661] [levelValue: 800] [[
  expenditures was successfully deployed in 521 milliseconds.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish 4+ uses Jersey 2.x The web.xml configuration you have is for Jersey 1.x. For 2.x, the configuration would be

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.expenditures</param-name>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

As you are learning Jersey, when you are searching for tutorials, just keep in mind that whenever you see `com.sun.jersey` anywhere, this is Jersey 1.x. Jersey 2.x will be `org.glassfish.jersey` packaging.

Also, since you are using Glassfish, the server already has all the Jersey jars. To avoid doubling up incompatible versions of jars, it is recommended to use a "provided" scope, which would cause the build system to only use the projects jars to compile, but would not build it into the final artifact to be deployed to the server. The concept of `scope` is something that is for Maven. I don't use Gradle too much, but I think they have a similar concept. Where you use `compile` in your dependency declaration, I think there might be something else you can use to get the "provided" functionality. You will have to research more about this as I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick reply, Paul. I have updated the web.xml as indicated, but I still get the mystery 404s. Anything else jump out to you?

Comment: Can you confirm that your application is deployed to the server?

Comment: By convention the `web.xml` should be in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`. This is the standard web app packaging in Gradle and Maven. And Java classes should be in `src/main/java`. You should stick to this convention.

Comment: My hunch is that the app has not actually deployed. That said, the log above suggests otherwise (as does http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf -> Applications, which lists "expenditures").

Is there another way you'd verify it's live? I just changed my directory structure to match convention with no results (thanks for the suggestion--will keep in mind).

Comment: I don't know. I don't use Gradle or Glassfish. You might want to search for an article on how to deploy a Gradle app to Glassfish.